# how to configure django-froala-editor to upload images to aws S3 bucket

Tags: django, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am working on Django2.2.6 apps and one of the model filed is `FroalaField` where users can upload images from their machine local storage, the default Django models.FileField has a defualt upload_to attribute like this models.FileField(upload_to=get_blog_filepath, null=True, blank=True), how can I configure FroalaField to upload images to S3 by passing the url, I have looked at the docs and didn't find something useful in my case.

```
from django.db import models
from froala_editor.fields import FroalaField

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    short_title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False, db_column='db_short_title')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blurb = FroalaField(max_length=300) # how I can do upload_to S3
    report_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_blog_filepath, null=True, blank=True)
```